# How can I list AMDGPU VRAM usage by process?

Tags: linux, memory, monitoring, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I've got an AMDGPU on Linux and want to be able to see which processes are utilising my precious 4GB of VRAM I need for gaming.

I'd like this to be presented in a similar manner to `top` listing all processes utilising VRAM by usage.

`radeontop` only shows total VRAM usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One tool to accomplish this task is https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/tomstdenis/umr

```
sudo umr -t
```

Will start it in a `top`-like view. You can then hit `v` to see VRAM information per-process.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to determine your card number, this will typically be card0 or card1. If you only have one card in your system, you can look it up using `ls -la /sys/class/drm`.

Replace `card1` with whatever is the correct one for you.

```
cat /sys/class/drm/card1/device/mem_info_vram_used
```

And for total VRAM:

```
cat /sys/class/drm/card1/device/mem_info_vram_total
```

To get the usage in MiB:

```
echo $(($(</sys/class/drm/card1/device/mem_info_vram_used)/1024/1024)) MiB
```

Percentage used:

```
echo $(($(</sys/class/drm/card1/device/mem_info_vram_used)*100/$(</sys/class/drm/card1/device/mem_info_vram_total)))%
```

Comment: This only shows total VRAM usage, not per-process which was asked for in the question.

Comment: This is a great answer, even if its not exactly what was asked for.

Comment: @Atemu I'm sorry about that, I kind of forgot that specific point. I found this question while looking for how to get the VRAM usage in general and answered it too quickly. I'm leaving this answer here for the ones who find it useful. For everyone else, I'd recommend this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1066053/454700 (use radeontop or glances)